# How to align {cases} block to the left

Tags: amsmath

I've got a `{cases}` block inside of an item list, how can I get the block to float to the left?

[image]

I've tried `flalign` and `align` but it doesn't appear to work

```
\item \[ f(x) = \begin{cases} 
  0 & x\leq 0 \\
  \frac{100-x}{100} & 0\leq x\leq 100 \\
  0 & 100\leq x 
  \end{cases}
\]
```

Comment: Welcome! Please show us a minimal code in order to reproduce your status quo. We do not want to guess and less to setup that problem for you. Thanks.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Updated the question

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Although in this case your example should suffice, for future reference a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) should start with `\documentclass`, has the relevant packages in the preamble and ends with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use inline math here:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $f(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
        0 & x\leq 0 \\
        \frac{100-x}{100} & 0\leq x\leq 100 \\
        0 & 100\leq x 
    \end{cases}
    $
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

---

You may also take a look on `dcases` which will result in display style formulae. In this case, the fraction will look bigger (as set as `\dfrac{}{}`).